When are two polynomials with similar roots identical?
Claim:- Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two polynomials of degree $n$ such that coefficient of $x^{n}$ is same for both $f,g$ and their roots are identical and multiplicity of every root is $1$. Then
$$f(x)=g(x)$$
Proof:-
Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}$ and $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}b_{k}x^{k}$
Let their roots be $r_1,r_2,...,r_n$ then it follows that,
$$f(x)=a_{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-r_{k}\right)$$
$$g(x)=b_{n}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\left(x-r_{k}\right)$$
Since by our assumption $a_{n}=b_{n}$ we have that,
$$f(x)=g(x)$$.
My query:-
Are there any mistakes in the proof?

This assumes the roots are distinct. $x^2(x-1)$ and $x(x-1)^2$ are two degree $3$ polynomials with the same roots, $0,1,$ but they are different polynomials.

@Thomas Andrews, Thanks for the suggestion of multiplicity. I edited my claim. I think considering that every root has no multiplicity makes the claim true. Please let me know if there are any mistakes.

The statement is false, unless it takes into account the multiplicities of the roots as well. A simple counterexample is given by @ThomasAndrews in the comments (consider $x^2(x-1)$ and $x(x-1)^2$).
Taking multiplicities into account, it is straightforward:
$$f(x)=a_n\prod_{i=1}^r(x-r_i)^{m_i}=g(x)$$
Hope this helps. :)

I edited the claim taking multiplicity as zero. Are there any mistakes now?

@RAHUL: you mean multiplicity $1$. Then, the proof is fine.
